# How to insert a div at specific postion in an array in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have an array and when I am retriving my array I am getting something like this.

```
arr[0] = <li data="Dummy1" class= "Dummy1"></li>
arr[1] = <li data="Dummy2" class= "Dummy2"></li>
arr[2] = <li data="Dummy3" class= "Dummy3"></li>
```

Now after arr[0] I wanted to insert a div with style of cursor

```
<div style: 'cursor:auto'></div>
```

so my array will be look like

```
arr[0] = <li data="Dummy1" class= "Dummy1"></li>
arr[1] = <div style: 'cursor:auto'></div>
arr[2] = <li data="Dummy2" class= "Dummy2"></li>
arr[3] = <li data="Dummy3" class= "Dummy3"></li>
```

Can anybody help me how to achive this'

Answer (score 3):

you can use this way the `splice` function on the array object:

```
arr.splice(1, 0, "<div style: 'cursor:auto'></div>");
```

This will insert the item in index 1 deleting 0 items.

Answer (score 1):

**Use [Array.splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice?v=example) method :** It will changes the contents of an array by removing existing elements and/or adding new elements.

```js
var arr = [];

arr[0] = '<li data="Dummy1" class= "Dummy1"></li>';
arr[1] = '<li data="Dummy2" class= "Dummy2"></li>';
arr[2] = '<li data="Dummy3" class= "Dummy3"></li>';

arr.splice(1, 0, "<div style: 'cursor:auto'></div>");

console.log(arr);
```